# WKWebView html5 embedded video plays on simulator but not on real device

Tags: video, xcode8, ios10, wkwebview, simulator

I'm working in an App that contains a WKWebView to load html5 files. some of those files contains .mp4 videos which should be reproduced on touch de play button.

In the simulator the videos are played without problems, but in a real device only the sound can be heard, while the image is only seen when the pause button is pressed.

The code I use to load index.html files with the embedded videos is:

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let htmlTmp = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("data/index.html")
webview.loadFileURL(htmlTmp, allowingReadAccessTo: documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("data/"))
```

Any possible solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow inline media playback in the configuration for WKWebView.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration

Comment: I've tried this but didn't work. After a lot of googling it seems to be something that begins to happen on iOS 10.2.